# Swift escaping closure not executed

Tags: ios, swift

I want to execute some code using escaping closure, but it's not working. Can you tell me what is wrong with this example?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("Calling getData")
        getData(completion: {
            print("Escaping closure getData")
        })

        print("Returning from getData")

        print("Calling doSomething")
        doSomething (completion: {
            print("Escaping closure doSomething")
        })
        print("Returning from doSomething")
    }

    func getData(completion: @escaping () ->Void)
    {
        print ("Begin getData")
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error)  in
            print ("Escaping closure dataTask")

            guard error == nil else {
                print("Error calling GET API: \(error!)")
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        print ("Ending getData")
    }

    func doSomething(completion: @escaping () ->Void)
    {
        print ("Begin doSomething")
        sleep(3)
        print ("Ending doSomething")
    }
}
```

The `print("Escaping closure getData")` and `print("Escaping closure doSomething")` are never executed.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that you never actually call the closure inside your function.

```
func getData(completion: @escaping () ->Void){
    print ("Begin getData")
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error)  in
        print ("Escaping closure dataTask")

        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error calling GET API: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        print ("Ending getData")
        completion()
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Some other generic issues: `print ("Ending getData")` should be inside the completion handler of `URLSession.dataTask(with:)`, otherwise it will get called before the network request would actually finish execution.

You shouldn't use `sleep()`, since it blocks the main thread as well, hence making your whole app unresponsive.

You rarely want empty completion handlers. What you would usually implement is a closure with two or more optional input arguments, one for each return value and one for the error.

```
func getData(completion: @escaping (Data?,Error?) ->Void){
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error)  in
            guard error == nil, let data = data else {
                completion(nil,error)
                return
            } 
            //In general you would also convert `data` into a more suitable format, in your case, you would deserialize the JSON
            completion(data,nil)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Then call it like this:

```
getData({ data, error in
    guard error == nil, let data = data else {
        //handle the error here
        return
    }
    //use the value from the network request
})
```

Comment: Thanks, very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your `completion` closures when your async tasks are done.  For example, your `getData` should look more like this:

```
func getData(completion: @escaping () ->Void) {
    print ("Begin getData")
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error)  in
        print ("Escaping closure dataTask")

        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error calling GET API: \(error!)")
            completion()  //-------Here, before returning
            return
        }
        completion()  //--------Here, after your task is done (and error free)
    }
    task.resume()
    print ("Ending getData")
}
```